# Single pole 120 v thermostat

Tags: electrical

I want to use a thermostat to control a 40 watt. I am using the bulb to heat the inside of a small green house. The temperature must stay in the range of 75 TO 79 degrees.  I want to use 120 v and not a low voltage thermostat. What do you recommend?

Comment: Would an aquarium heater work, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07HB1LHHT/ref=sspa_dk_detail_2 ? You would need to place it in water in the greenhouse, but that might be an advantage, keeping humidity high.

Answer (score 2):

StackExchange is not for *product recommendations*.   However, any of the simple, mechanical $13 "mains wiring" 240V type thermostats should suffice, and a 1-pole unit will suffice.   (On 2-pole, only one one pole is switched thermostatically, the other is simply an off switch.   They mount in a standard junction box.

Do not use an incandescent bulb when you want a heater, it is cruel: incandescents burn out randomly and then the poor creature suffers until you notice to replace it. **Use a heater**.  Catalogs like McMaster-Carr and Grainger sell lots and lots of heating components.

You can either use a 120V heater of your desired wattage, or a 240V heater of **four times** the wattage.  For instance if you want 50W and you see a heater that is perfect except for being 240V and 200W, that will do exactly what you want: draw 50W if you connect it to 120V.

Answer (score 0):

A green house even a tiny one would need more than 40w to maintain 75-79 degrees. There are lots of brands of line voltage thermostats out there, cheap bimetalic types for less than 15$ up to fancy programmable digital models for around 75$. Without knowing your location or the size of greenhouse it would be a total guess on the size of heater but even a small 4'x8' room would probably take 2500w to 5kw to keep the area that warm.